# How to start a simulation with the experiment screen in AnyLogic Cloud?

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent-based model built by AnyLogic. I can run it correctly with an experiment screen where I configure parameters and then click a button to start simulation in the desktop version. However, it skips the experiment screen and directly runs the simulation when I upload it to the **AnyLogic Cloud**.

How can I start a simulation WITH the experiment screen in AnyLogic Cloud?

I tried to setup the run configuration here:

[Run configuration for AnyLogic Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BubKs.png)

Also, I tried to use commands like: `pauseSimulation()`, `runSimulation()`, and `getEngine().stop()`, in Java actions on Simulation page and Agent actions on Main page.

[Java actions on simulation Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Liu.png)

[Agent actions on main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4icQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A new and better solution is found to the question.**

You can create an `event` which occurs only once at the very first beginning of the simulation (i.e., time = 0). This event carries out a function called: `pauseSimulation();`.

Now, the model should pause at the beginning.

Next, move the welcome page (experiment screen) that you created from the `Simulation` domain to the `Main`. You need to further specify a function in the same `event` to *navigate* to the `view area` of your welcome page. For example, `areaName.navigateTo();`.

Finally, select `Skip experiment screen and run the model` in the Properties of Simulation domain. Your model should now start with your welcome page. Remember to create a button on the welcome page to `runSimulation();`.

Comment: true, but it does not answer the original question ("How can I start a simulation WITH the experiment screen") -> you can't. But you can, of course, duplicate it in your model. Just be careful as this may cause issues with replicated runs, etc.

Comment: Yes, Benjamin, you are correct. Thank you for your additions!

Comment: thank you for sharing a fair workaround with the community, keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse IDE experiments in the cloud, you have to re-create them from scratch. The RunConfig allows you to "open" all parameters you want to use in your cloud experiments.

But then, it is up to you to create new cloud experiments, see the help. https://anylogic.help/cloud/experiment-dashboard.html